# How can I fit a DN16 flange to a DN10 flanged pipe?

Tags: steam, piping

One of the valves on my 3 bar line just failed. Without it, our production has ground to a stop and we can't operate until we get a replacement (which we have already ordered). In order to make a deadline, I am trying to find a way to use a (properly rated for pressure) DN 16 flanged valve to fit with the existing DN 10 piping.

Is there any way to (safely) connect these two flanges together temporarily?

Comment: Can you find a flanged reducer? We use these all the time in our production plant. They especially are useful for changing the diameter of the line when installing fittings.

Comment: @tralston don't have a proper one on hand / can't get one faster than the proper valve.

Comment: @jmac if you cannot get a flanged reducer, are you able to connect your system via another pipe with different flanges on each side?

Comment: Can you just Zeus it on with a weld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a lathe you should be able to quickly machine a flanged reducer out of [Nylon 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon_6). Not sure what temperature you're operating at but make it a bit thick and it will easily be able to handle 3 bar.